# How to add OpenMPI to Codeblocks?

Tags: module, installation, codeblocks, openmpi

I am trying to use OpenMPI on Code:Blocks.
I have only used it before on a remote server where i just had to bash `load module ...` and everything was fine. 
In code::blocks this seems to be a bit more involved, but i am sure quite easy.
I am using a windows, however there are only linux files available on their website ?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is [no longer](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.6/ms-windows.php) a supported platform for Open MPI (since 1.7 or so). However, MPI has a standard API and you don't need to develop your application with a specific MPI implementation. In Windows, you could just as well use [Microsoft MPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/microsoft-mpi), which
is freely available (including SDK in a separate installer) from the Microsoft web.

I assume that you are using C/C++, a GCC-based compiler and 64-bit aplications.

All I needed to do to enable MPI in Code::Blocks was the following:

1. In project build options, add "Search directories" / "Compiler":
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include`
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\x64`
2. Also, add "Linker settings" / "Link libraries":
   `C:\Windows\System32\msmpi.dll`

When using the "Run" or "Build and Run" button in Code::Blocks, the application will be started in one process. If execution of multiple processes is desired as well, you will need to do that in a terminal outside of Code::Blocks by means of the program `mpiexec.exe` located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin`.